# How can I add GPS data to an Excel with postal addresses

Tags: excel, web-services, google-maps, gps, waze

When I have an excel file that would include a postal address (street , postal code, city) departure and an arrival address, is there a web service or anything else directly to open its GPS or Google maps API kind .

Is this possible and where can I find information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have [Google Earth Pro](https://www.google.com/earth/download/gep/agree.html) (which is free now), you can [import Excel file to GPS location](https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148104?hl=en).  Save your Excel sheet as a CSV (or .txt, tab delimited).  Then, in Google Earth, go to File --> Import, and choose your file.  From there, follow the prompts.

In the end, it should place the markers at your various locations on the globe.

Comment: Thanks a lot, we'll try If it's free it's quiet perfect !  Regards, Ava

Comment: @AvaConti - What's nice about this too, is once the data is in Google Earth, you can right click and save the file as a .KMZ (or maybe it's KML), and then you can send that to people and they can open and see the locations as well.